# Calculate $ \lim_{\left(x,y\right)\to\left(0,0\right)}\frac{\sin\left(x^{3}+y^{3}\right)}{\sin\left(x^{2}+y^{2}\right)} $

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

I have to calculate $ \lim_{\left(x,y\right)\to\left(0,0\right)}\frac{\sin\left(x^{3}+y^{3}\right)}{\sin\left(x^{2}+y^{2}\right)} $

From wolfram calculator I know the limit is $ 0 $. The onl way I cant think of proving it is switch to polar, and to show that $ \lim_{r\to0}\frac{\sin\left(r^{3}\left(\cos^{3}\theta+\sin^{3}\theta\right)\right)}{\sin\left(r^{2}\right)} $ is $ 0$.

If I'll treat $ \theta $ as a constant and I'll get that the limit is zero, is that mean that from any direction that the function getting closer to zero, the limit is zero?

If so, I could show it using l'Hospital's rule and I guess it would be easy, but I'm not sure its legit.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Wolfram alpha often makes mistakes evaluating multivariable limits. (not saying is the case)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen This one is strictly related but not the same question.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Moreover note that here the asker is seeking for a check of their method (i.e. poalr coordinates + linear paths). Can you see the difference? We can link the related question but it is not a duplicate.

Comment: @user I doubt anyone here has trouble incorporating that extra factor $\cos(x^3+y^3)$ missing from this variant. This might not be a duplicate, if it were ONLY about the OP's method. I don't see you addressing their question about the use of l'Hospital. I only see you reproducing the same answer you have already done dozens if not hundreds of times.

Comment: Look at the other answers also. They prove that this is a duplicate. Mind you this is a common problem with all solution-verification questions. But did you notice that the asker didn't tag this [tag:solution-verification]. That also points at this being a duplicate.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen That's a good point but maybe it is just a tag issue. The problem is clearly stated to have a clarification on the method used. I've not added comment for l'Hospital because the method to assume $\theta$ constant fails to prove the limit and therefore also l'Hospital is useless (note that the asker says "If so..."). You probably don't like my answer but it is another issue. I can try to improve it. But the question is not a duplicate.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I don't think that the question is a duplicate but I do think it is the answerers' shortfall that they were not able to address the OP's confusion. I have updated my answer to better address them.

Comment: Thanks @ShubhamJohri. User, I'm dropping this case.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thanks Jyrki to have reconsidered your position. I also have added some more information about the issue the asker is looking for.

Answer (score 3):

By your way the result is not immediately clear, as previously suggested by Mark Viola, we can use that

$$\frac{\sin\left(x^{3}+y^{3}\right)}{\sin\left(x^{2}+y^{2}\right)}=
\frac{\sin\left(x^{3}+y^{3}\right)}{x^3+y^3}
\frac{x^2+y^2}{\sin\left(x^{2}+y^{2}\right)}\frac{x^{3}+y^{3}}{x^{2}+y^{2}}$$

and using standard limits we reduce to evaluate the simpler

$$\lim_{\left(x,y\right)\to\left(0,0\right)}\frac{x^{3}+y^{3}}{x^{2}+y^{2}}$$

---

Note that assuming $\theta$ constant corresponds to take the limit by linear path (i.e. $y=mx$) and we can't conclude that the limit is zero in this way.

More in general we can't prove the limit existence by this way, as noticed by Mark Viola in the comments, "we can show a limit fails to exist by showing that the value of the limit has different results along different paths. But we don't show the existence by looking at the limit along paths".

We need to use some bounding and squeeze theorem to conclude, that is in this case

$$\frac{x^{3}+y^{3}}{x^{2}+y^{2}}=r (\cos^3 \theta + \sin^3 \theta) \to 0$$

since by squeeze theorem

$$\left|r (\cos^3 \theta + \sin^3 \theta)\right|=r\left|\cos^3 \theta + \sin^3 \theta\right| \le 2r \to 0$$

Comment: @MarkViola Why have you deleted your fine answer?

Comment: The OP is asking a much broader question.  Students are often misled to believe that a limit is associated with a "path."  But that is flawed.  We can show a limit fails to exist by showing that the value of the limit has different results along different paths.  But we don't show the existence by looking at the limit along paths.

Comment: @MarkViola Exactly, indeed I've added something also to this point. Thanks

Comment: Can tou show how those limits really equals to 1? Im aware to the fact that ita true in one variable but not sure how to see it in 2 dimensions

Comment: @FreeZe Just set $x^2+y^2=t \to 0$ or $x^3+y^3=t \to 0$ to conclude. More in general for any $f(x) \to 0$ (with $f(x)\neq 0$ for $x\neq 0$) we have $$\frac{\sin (f(x))}{f(x)} \to 1$$

Comment: @user Yes.  In fact, all possible paths would include stochastic paths.

Comment: (+1) with the edit. Many students have misconception that the notion of a limit is associated with a path defined by a deterministic relationship between $y$ and $x$.  Imagine for example a stochastic path.

Comment: @MarkViola Yes that's really a relevant point for the misconception of limits in multivariable case. Thanks for your contribution.

Comment: @user Isnt denoting $ x^2+y^2 = t$ means that you chose a specific path ? I mean, is there a theorem about changing the variables that can justify your claims?

Comment: @FreeZe No it isn't the same, here we are just using that $\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} x^2+y^2=0$ and we denote the quantity with $t$.

Answer (score 3):

In your solution, you take $\theta$ constant with respect to $r$ and use l'Hospital. This proves that the limit is $0$ along straight line paths $y=x\tan\theta$ through the origin. But this doesn't prove that the limit exists in general. While here the limit exists and is equal to $0$, [here is a question of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3344035/lim-r-to0fr-cos-theta-r-sin-theta-0-does-not-imply-lim-x-y-to0-0f) posted about an year ago where I found that the limit may not exist despite having the same value along all straight line paths.

---

You can solve it like this: if $x^3+y^3=0$ i.e. along $y=-x$, the numerator is $0$ so the limit is $0$.

If $x^3+y^3\ne0$, then$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{\sin(x^3+y^3)}{x^3+y^3}\times\frac{x^2+y^2}{\sin(x^2+y^2)}\times\frac{x^3+y^3}{x^2+y^2}$$The first two terms are standard limits equal to $1$. You can write $\frac{x^3+y^3}{x^2+y^2}$ in polar coordinates as $r(\cos^3\theta+\sin^3\theta)$, so the limit is$$\lim_{r\to0}r(\cos^3\theta+\sin^3\theta)=0$$

Comment: can you show why the limit of the sin over its argument is 1? Im familier with it in 1 variable but cant understand why ita true for 2 variables also

Comment: @FreeZe Well, you can just assume $m=x^3+y^3$. Then we have $\lim_{m\to0}\frac{\sin m}m=1$

Comment: @FreeZe I have added some information about the error in your method realizing that you were foremost interested in knowing whether *your* approach is correct.

Comment: @ShubhamJohri You refer to "arbitrary curved paths."  But the definition of the limit has nothing to do with paths.  That is to say that a limit is not approached along a path.  Moreover, all curved paths would exclude all possible paths (imagine a stochastic path).

Comment: @MarkViola Does my recent edit make it better?

Comment: Yes.  It is better.  Many students have misconception that the notion of a limit is associated with a path defined by a deterministic relationship between $y$ and $x$.

Answer (score 2):

You can just note that
$$
\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\dfrac{\sin(x^3+y^3)}{\sin(x^2+y^2)} = \lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{x^3+y^3}{x^2+y^2}
$$

and, regarding this last limit, since

$$
\left|\frac{x^3+y^3}{x^2+y^2} \right|\leq \frac{|x|^3+|y|^3}{x^2+y^2}\leq \frac{2(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}}{x^2+y^2}=\sqrt{x^2+y^2} \to 0
$$

we conclude that the original limit exists and is zero.

note: I'm using the fact that $|x|, |y| \leq \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$.

Comment: (+1) for this post.  But it doesn't really address the OP's misconception that the notion of a limit is associated with a path defined by a deterministic relationship between $y$ and $x$.

Comment: @MarkViola You're right. When I first read through the OP I did not spot the misconception you mention... When he fixed $\theta$ I just assumed he was saying that the limit as $r \to 0$ is zero, uniformly on $\theta$. But after a second read, I'm not so sure anymore!

Answer (score 0):

You can use inequality $\frac 12|u|\le |\sin(u)|\le |u|$ for small $|u|<1$ (it is true on a bit larger interval, but this is not very important).

$$0\le \dfrac{|\sin(x^3+y^3)|}{|\sin(x^2+y^2)|}\le 2\dfrac{|x^3+y^3|}{|x^2+y^2|}\le 2\dfrac{|x|^3+|y|^3}{x^2+y^2}\le 2\,\underbrace{\max(|x|,|y|)}_{\to 0}\ \underbrace{\dfrac{x^2+y^2}{x^2+y^2}}_1\to 0$$

Comment: This is fine, but But it doesn't really address the OP's misconception that the notion of a limit is associated with a path defined by a deterministic relationship between $y$ and $x$.